# Is it possible to add :before to existing :before

Tags: html, css

Good day, Im just doing some experiment for my learning, is it possible to add :before tag to existing :before tag, as you can see the image on the image which i created tru figma the gray background is already in :before tag now i want to add the text 'design' inside of it which, is there such a way to do it or it is posible?
[image: Design in Figma]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700,800,900&display=swap');

* 
{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 100px;
}

.container::before
{
    content: 'Design';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 330px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #767373;
    color: color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    z-index: -2;
}

header 
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

header .logo 
{
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
}

header .logo span 
{
    color: #004585;
}

header ul 
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
header ul li 
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

header ul li a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="logo">Jury<span>Design</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking about something like `.container::before:before`? You can't

Comment: Yes, what possible ways to achieve it?

Comment: What exactly do you need to change in the `:before`?

Comment: i just want to add the word design inside of it

Comment: That's what I don't understand - Because you did add that word here `content: 'Design';`

Comment: yes indeed i add the word, however i cant design that word that would be like to the image

Comment: Oh, so you can change `content: 'Design';` to `content: '';`, and use `.container::after` to design the word (`.container::after{ content: 'Design'; <rest_of_the_word_style> }`)

Comment: It is possible to produce the result in the screenshot by adding extra CSS to the current `::before` - see [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/GRgjXqr) - so I'm not sure why you didn't simply start asking about that.